# With MUI v5 how can I customize the SpeedDialAction label?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My ultimate goal here is to customize our `SpeedDial` instance so that:

- the labels (tooltips) are always visible
- the labels are wide enough to show the text without wrapping

For the first part, I have figured out that, to show the labels permanently, I have to set the `tooltipOpen` property. That was easy.

The problem I am running into is actually adjusting the style of the tooltip. I can do it fine when using `sx` directly, but I am unable to make that work in a reusable fashion, for example, using `styled()`. I also do not want to update the global/default style.

```tsx
import FileCopyIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileCopyOutlined";
import {
  styled,
  Box,
  SpeedDial,
  SpeedDialIcon,
  SpeedDialAction,
} from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSpeedDial() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 320, transform: "translateZ(0px)", flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <SpeedDial
        ariaLabel="SpeedDial basic example"
        sx={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 16, right: 16 }}
        icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
      >
        <SpeedDialAction
          icon={<FileCopyIcon />}
          tooltipTitle="Copy the File"
          tooltipOpen
          sx={{
            "& .MuiSpeedDialAction-staticTooltipLabel": {
              width: "8rem",
            },
          }}
        />
        <SDA1
          icon={<FileCopyIcon />}
          tooltipTitle="Copy the File"
          tooltipOpen
        />
        <SDA2
          icon={<FileCopyIcon />}
          tooltipTitle="Copy the File"
          tooltipOpen
        />
      </SpeedDial>
    </Box>
  );
}

const SDA1 = styled(SpeedDialAction)({
  "& .MuiSpeedDialAction-staticTooltipLabel": {
    width: "8rem",
  },
});

const SDA2 = styled(SpeedDialAction)({
  root: {
    "& .MuiSpeedDialAction-staticTooltipLabel": {
      width: "8rem",
    },
  },
});
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see, I cannot seem to make a *styled* version of the `SpeedDialAction`. I could use an object array with the icon, the label and the action to take on click, but really want to better understand how the whole `sylted` approach works.
Every time I figure something out about the approach, I think I go it, then it doesn't work in the next situation.
For example, below is an example from our code of successfully creating a styled reusable `Chip` component:

```tsx
const CancelledChip = styled(Chip)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.error.main, 0.9),
  color: theme.palette.error.main,
  "& .MuiChip-icon": {
    color: theme.palette.error.main,
  },
}));
```

I have confirmed and the static styles (without the `theme`) do not seem to change the behavior.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I reread your question and understand now, that it's more about understanding the `styled` function, which I can't really help, sorry. But still, for a reusable approach of actually getting the tooltip to not wrap, I leave my answer here.

**TL;DR**: `useTheme` + `useMemo` + 'stylesOverrides'

I ran into a similar problem. The `styled` function applies its styles to the root of the component, but not to child- or pseudo-elements, which the tooltip is one of.

This leaves us with the `sx` prop, which you don't want to use or with `stylesOverrides`. To make the latter reusable, you can provide a speed dial actions theme provider, which overrides the tooltip styles.

**EXAMPLE**

Following is a similar speed dial component to what I use, so you may need to adapt it to your use case:

```
import FileCopyIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FileCopyOutlined';
import SpeedDial from '@mui/material/SpeedDial';
import SpeedDialAction from '@mui/material/SpeedDialAction';
import SpeedDialIcon from '@mui/material/SpeedDialIcon';
import { createTheme, ThemeOptions, ThemeProvider, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useMemo } from 'react';

const speedDialActionOverrides: ThemeOptions = {
    components: {
        MuiSpeedDialAction: {
            styleOverrides: {
                staticTooltipLabel: {
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

const TestDial = () => {
    // extend the existing theme with some overrides
    const existingTheme = useTheme();
    const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(existingTheme, speedDialActionOverrides), [existingTheme]);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            {/* apply the extended theme to this speed dial */}
            <SpeedDial ariaLabel="Example Speed Dial" icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}>
                <SpeedDialAction icon={<FileCopyIcon />} tooltipTitle="Copy the File" tooltipOpen />
            </SpeedDial>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default TestDial;
```